# What is the extent of inertia manipulation powers?

Tags: super-powers

To my understanding, inertia is an object's resistance to change in motion, i.e. something with high inertia is more difficult to start/stop, and something with low inertia finds it easier to start/stop. If someone had the ability to manipulate the inertia of themselves and objects/people near them, what would the extent of this power be?

I know that they could be a lot more maneuverable by decreasing their inertia, or could turn themselves into an unstoppable force/immovable object by increasing their inertia, but would the following fall under this power's scope?

- They can run faster and jump higher by putting in the same effort as regular people. If their inertia is low and it takes less effort to move them, they can make larger leaps.
- By decreasing the inertia of objects/enemies and hitting them, they have pseudo-superstrength, and objects/enemies will go flying through the air.
- Jumping off a ten-story building and decreasing inertia on the way down. They take no fall damage, as they require less of a force to stop them, therefore the ground exerts 'less' of a force on them when they land. Similarly, if they are thrown into a wall by an opponent, they can decrease their inertia mid-flight so that whenever they hit the wall, the wall will exert a smaller force on them, and they won't be injured -- they're effectively immune to blunt force trauma.
- Decreasing the inertia of an attacking opponent. They have pseudo-invulnerability because as soon as their opponent's fist hits their face, it loses its momentum.
- Similar to above -- bullets just bounce off their skin as it takes very little to make them stop.
- If they were to turn themself into an immovable object, would they take damage when coming into contact with obstacles? Or would that only be the case if they managed to decrease the inertia of said obstacles first?
- They find acrobatics easier and can do flips etc. with less effort since they can decrease their rotational inertia as well.

Comment: Inertia is really just a way of describing the net vectors of kinetic energy of an object. I think it would end up being not that different than a limited form of telekinesis. Everything telekinetic, except you can't actually change an object's direction (except you can, by reducing inertia to zero and allowing other natural forces to move an object in the opposite direction).

Comment: If you just think about the inertia of individual atoms vibrating, if they all always vibrate left with extra force, and vibrate right with less, the object moves left. Air stops moving and becomes a solid. You could compress it like an explosive by simply letting it move into a space with force and not allowing it to move out.

Comment: That would require a whole host of complementary perceptual abilities. Atoms vibrate randomly. How could you control all those random vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this. By decoupling inertia from mass/speed, you have probably broken a lot of fundamental laws of physics and caused atoms to no longer exist, but we can ignore those now and focus on the macro level for a flavourful set of powers.

Regarding your listing:

- They can run faster

Yes, but not as much as you might think. Lowering inertia makes one essentially massless during the acceleration, making the amount of force your muscles produce sufficient for whatever you wish to do that involves moving your own body... limited by the speed at which your muscles contract. It is like the top speed of a car; even if you run it in a vacuum with zero resistance, the motor cannot physically go any faster than its mechanics allow.

[This study](https://www.jick.net/%7Ejess/p438/phys438/Reports/MuscleContractionSpeed) of human muscle contraction speed is long and enlightening, but the top value it suggests by the end is around 13 meters per second. So that is the ceiling; you cannot make any part of the body go faster than that, even if there were no resistance.

That is about 45 km/h for running. Maybe you can get a bit better by angling your leg muscles so you are utilising the top speed of every individual muscle to the fullest extent, but you will not be breaking the sound barrier with zero inertia.

- and jump higher

Again, your magicians are limited by the muscle contraction speed. They can get their bodies to fly upwards at that velocity, 13 m/s, but then gravity takes over and you will inevitably plummet back down.

The maximum height that may be achieved ends up at [8.6 meters](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=calculate%20trajectory%20angle%2090%20degrees%20mass%2070%20kg%20speed%2013%20m%2Fs). Don't forget to also make the air around you have zero inertia, so you can push it out of the way and have no resistance!

Through lever action you could multiply this by a factor. I am personally not qualified to judge how much the force is multiplied through the various muscles involved in jumping; it would depend on the direction and angle too, which muscles would be utilised fully and which only partially. So consider this speed an order-of-magnitude estimation. Leaping higher than 10 meters is believable, reaching airplane cruising altitudes is not.

Alternatively, consider keeping the body free of inertia but increasing that of air below your hands and feet. You could crawl up through the air and gradually achieve whatever height you want!

- By decreasing the inertia of objects/enemies and hitting them, they have pseudo-superstrength, and objects/enemies will go flying through the air.

Yes, with the magic 13 m/s limitation. You can use the same wolfram link for some trajectory calculations :)

- They take no fall damage, as they require less of a force to stop them, therefore the ground exerts 'less' of a force on them when they land.

Yes; in surviving falls there is no limitation.

- Decreasing the inertia of an attacking opponent. They have pseudo-invulnerability because as soon as their opponent's fist hits their face, it loses its momentum.

To an extent. You are removing the built-up momentum from the equation (if you remember to de-inertia-fy the enemy's whole body, not just their fist); but what's left is the same as if the person starts with the weapon on your skin and then starts pushing it against you violently. That can still cause bruising, and if their weapon is sharp, it may not actually lose any lethality!

- bullets just bounce off their skin

Yes. Rockets on the other hand...

- If they were to turn themself into an immovable object, would they take damage when coming into contact with obstacles?

Now this would be harder. If you amp up your inertia and go running into a solid wall, then what you need to focus on is the inertia of the top layer of your skin. That's what you don't want to compress; if it budges even slightly then you are squeezing your flesh and injuring yourself.

As it happens, the top part of your skin does not weigh all that much. So to get the inertia high enough that it is effectively immobile, you will need a lot more work than to render one's own body inertia-less. Possible, but it would be a more strenuous use of the power.

- Or would that only be the case if they managed to decrease the inertia of said obstacles first?

Only if said obstacle is not attached to anything. A brick wall is tough not just because of its mass, but because it is cemented to the rest of the building. Even if it weighed as little as paper, that would not make it fragile as paper.

- They find acrobatics easier and can do flips etc. with less effort since they can decrease their rotational inertia as well.

Acrobatics is a broad skill with a wide range of movements, some of which would benefit much more from inertia control than others. On the whole, you are right.

Comment: "Don't forget to also make the air around you have zero inertia..." Good God, nooooo! Lower that inertia by an amount _within reason_, because an object with **zero** inertia will move with the speed of light. Once out of your control, you are so much worse than being enveloped by O(10^23) of [Oh-My-God particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle)... (an effect that may worth weaponizing, if one can control it).

Comment: "Again, your magicians are limited by the muscle contraction speed. They can get their bodies to fly upwards at that velocity, 13 m/s," Disagree. The gastrocnemius and soleus muscles (the calf ones), those that attach to the Achilles tendon, work with a lever arm shorter at least 4 times than the one starting at (the ankle) fulcrum and ending with the toe. If the inertia of the body is lower, the toe speed pushing into the ground will be at least 4 times the contraction speed of those two muscles - assuming 13m/s, that's 52m/s. The next…umm… step is to wear longer shoes with rigid soles.

Comment: Muscles may contract at a certain capped speed, but there are such things as levers which (especially with no inertia) would have higher speeds at one end. Arms and legs are levers with fulcrums nearer one end...

Answer (score 1):

We now know that inertia is due to the Higgs Boson and the Higgs Field. It is the interaction between the boson and the field that causes the effects of inertia.

The Higgs field has been referred to as the sticky field, or the molasses field (like things moving through molasses), or the God particle (it is responsible for all mass). It is the boson-field that is responsible for the general equation **F=ma**. Think generally in terms of a magnetic particle and a magnetic field, except that apparently it is a 'one way field' like gravity, only in reverse - repulsion only, no attraction.

By manipulating either the Higgs boson of the Higgs field, one can theoretically alter that which we call 'inertia'.

If we could completely eliminate either the Higgs boson of the Higgs field, then we would completely eliminate inertia. All 'matter' would then act like a 'massless particle', in other words, like light. The catch-22 is, the inertia-less mass would not be able to 'run into' and 'be stopped' by another mass. It would just pass through another object, unimpeded by the concept of 'being hit'. One could not jump, hit another person, stop a ball, or deflect anything else. (Light does not actually 'reflect' off a mirror, it is actually absorbed by the mirror particles and then re-radiated. The ability to 're-radiate' the light in a cohesive direction based on the angle of incidence determines the reflectivity of the mirror.)

However, if one were able to INCREASE the strength of the Higgs Field or Higgs boson (add more bosons to the object?) one would increase the effects of **F=ma** considerably. It would take a much larger force to accelerate or decelerate something. Newton's Laws on steroids.

What I am not clear about is, when 'things' interact between each other, wrt the Higgs Field, is it a case of the bosons of one object interacting with the Higgs field of the other object? If, for instance, one were able to increase the Higgs field around one object (you) like one can adjust the electromagnetic field to hugely unimaginable strength, would that object become impenetrable by a Higgs boson of another object?

The latter is pure conjecture, the physics book is not yet thick enough to either allow or disallow, and is thus fair game to pass a speculative 'reality check' in science fiction. Thus, it would seem to me that an ability to alter or adjust the strength of the Higgs field locally would get you what you want. No idea, however, of the energies or energy source that would be required.

Bear in mind, nothing above changes anything about 'conservation of momentum'.